# OutSystems 5 - How to get values from web block

Tags: outsystems

I'm facing a problem when trying to get values from a web block. The content of the block is an `EditRecord` that correspond to submodel elements added dynamically to a page.

As **OutSystems 5** doesn't permit parameters passed by reference to a web block, I just can't get the updated values user input.

What are the alternatives to implement dynamic submodels in this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to help you, cause it's not easy to get a version 5 to try a couple of things out. One thing that you might want to try is to notify the parent page with your values stringified, but I'm not even sure if that exists in 5.

If I can ask, why still in 5?

Comment: Got it. You could try to fire hidden button click with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Outsystem new versions there is method name Deprecated_Notify   you can pass value from webblock  and in parent webscreen section you can get value from Deprecated_NotifyGetMessage() .